# Center map based on data from KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am showing some data over a map from a kml feed generated in my backend, I will like the ability to control the map based on data from the KML infowindow (description)

For example I have an infowindow from a point in KML that summarized all data, I will like to click to a link (a name for example) and that will Center the map to a certain lat,lon.

Is this possible, or what would be the best approach.

Comment: Are you asking if you can add links to the infoWindow that will center the map on a position that is contained in the data displayed in the infowindow?  Or do you want to add external links ([a clickable sidebar](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_icon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/visualisationmagazine_com_lacreativemap_kml.xml)) based on information in the kml?

Comment: @geocodezip thank you, a side could be also, I built a kml from php and after building all my placemark I add a last with the summary of the points (more or less the content of the sidebar) but is all inside  the kml.  check this link http://goo.gl/aj6mG and click on the **! sign** there is the summary I will like to zoom,center the map.

Comment: @geocodezip I added the kml to you script and I can see kml http://goo.gl/QfzyV but not the sidebar, how can I construct the sidebar ? is an interesting approach for me to.. thanks

Comment: You need to copy the script to your server (or [use a proxy](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_icon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://ajetrk.com/temp/dev/kmltest.kml)).  geoxml3 is subject to the XmlHttpRequest same domain restriction.

Comment: Thanks, will copy to my site to test..

Comment: @geocodezip thanks, the sidebar is working :-) I wanted to add a search/filter like this example http://jsfiddle.net/7BUmG/2/ but it does not work, seems is because the way the sidebar table is made. Could you guide me how to make this, or JS only approach, here is my map http://goo.gl/ascZF thanks.

Comment: That is grounds for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply add two attributes when creating the links with the KML information (understanding that you do have lat/lng coordinates in your KML data).

For example:

```
<a href='#' class='kml-link' data-lat='12.3456' data-lng='23.4567'>Click me to center on KML point</a>
```

And then do something like:

```
$('.kml-link').click(function () {

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr('data-lat'), $(this).attr('data-lng'));
    map.setCenter(latLng);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is using jQuery. If you need a simple javascript example, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer MrUpsidown, I forgot to mention the kml is overlayed the map, Is not parsed on the client. So the link should be added on the kml right? 

I haven't added jquery to the map but I guess is add the script only?,  I would love to have an example 

Thanks again

Comment: Where did you create those links?

Comment: here is a link of the current kml http://goo.gl/aj6mG click the **< ! Sign>** you will see the data I will like to add the link to.. thanks.

Comment: Well, yes, then where do you create that "Summary" table? Use the technique I proposed above to create your links and place them where you want in that table.

Comment: Thank you, based on your technique I should also add jquery script in the map right ?

Comment: Yes. Add jQuery library in a place that loads before you use the above code. Use `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`